# AddressBookSourceSync a virus?

Tags: activity-monitor, macos, virus

On my mac, in activity process, there are two processes that keep on running even though I stop them. They are AddressBookSourceSync and com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService. Is it possible that they are viruses or am I just being paranoid. How do I quit these? I tried everything but it keeps turning back on.

Comment: Have you tried force quitting them or restarting the computer? AddressBookSourceSync is a built-in Apple program relating to the address book (contacts) application

Comment: @NoahL Yes I force quitted, restarted but it is still there. Can you tell me what it is supposed to do? Maybe I can tell you if it is supposed to be running. I can't find much info on the internet. And the thing is I have never used the contacts application on my mac.

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't help you out: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3355782?start=45&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Taken from one of the answers in [this Apple Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3355782?start=45&tstart=0):

- Export all contacts to a vCard file for safe keeping.
- Delete Library --> Application Support --> Address Book.
- Reboot.
- Open System Preferences --> iCloud. Enable Contact Syncing.

Comment: What question or problem is this supposed to solve?